# how can i print this using String Methods

Tags: java, string

Given a `String`, return a `String` made of the `char`s at indexes 0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9... so "kittens" yields "kien".

```java
class FirstLastStr {
    public String altPairs(String str) {
        return str.substring(0, 2) 
                + str.substring(4, 6) 
                + str.substring(8, 10); //This part will throw string out of bound
    }
}
```

Comment: Good job posting your assignment. What is the problem you are having in doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers by you. 
I got my answer for my question as i was trying.. 
sorry for uploading it late but got so many other ways to do it. 
Here is my answer.

```
String res = "";
    public String altPairs(String str) {
        int i=0;
        while (i<str.length()) {
            res +=str.charAt(i);
            i=i+1;
            if(i<str.length()) {
                res+=str.charAt(i);
                i=i+3;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to return characters 8 and 9 from a string with 7 characters. You would simply have to check the string length before attempting the operation

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (str.size() > 2) {
    sb.append(str.substring(0,2));
}

if (str.size() > 6) {
    sb.append(str.substring(4,6));
}

if (str.size() > 10) {
    sb.append(str.substring(8,10));
}

return sb.toString();
```

Not the most efficient code, but this will wrk with your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class FirstLastStr 
{
    public String altPairs(String str) 
    {
        char[] arr = {str.charAt(0), str.charAt(1),str.charAt(4), str.charAt(5), str.charAt(8), str.charAt(9)};

        return new String(arr) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a function that gets two chars in a string and then skips 2 more, and returns the output as a string, you want this:

```java
public class FirstLastStr {
    public String altPairs(String str) 
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int current_char = 0; current_char + 2 <= str.length(); current_char += 4) {
            result.append(str.substring(current_char, current_char + 2));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

This returns proper output for strings of any length.

Example output:

```
'kittens' -> 'kien'
'cat' -> 'ca'
'at' -> 'at'
'a' -> ''
'' -> ''
'01234567890123456789' -> '0145892367'
```